# How to change Label text on a static string?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to put the total directory size on a label:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static string GetDirectorySize(string parentDir)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetDirectorySize(@"C:\example\"));
        long totalFileSize = 0;

        string[] dirFiles = Directory.GetFiles(parentDir, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string fileName in dirFiles)
        {
            // Use FileInfo to get length of each file.
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fileName);
            totalFileSize = totalFileSize + info.Length;
        }
        return totalFileSize.ToString();
    }
}
```

First question, should I being returning that string?

Second question, Now how do I change `label1.Text` with the info I got from the `totalFileSize`?

I tried to add this after the return:

```
      Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
      frm1.label1.Text = totalFileSize.ToString();
```

I get no error, but still, the label doesn't change... 
Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: This is a question and answer site. Notice that question is singular. Please edit your question to target a specific problem, or ask two questions.

Comment: Now the label1, I assume is a UI component. You can get the value of static string from the function after calling `InitializeComponent();` and change the value of label1 there. `label1.Text = GetDirectorySize("string");`

Comment: When do you want to change the text? At form load?

Comment: @Ahmar I did what you've said, please check if that's what is supose to look like: `label1.Text = GetDirectorySize(parentDir:ToString());`

But when I use that code, and execute the debug, I get this error: **System.StackOverflowException occurred
  HResult=0x800703E9**

When this happens, both `label1.Text = GetDirectorySize(parentDir:ToString());` and `Console.WriteLine(GetDirectorySize(@"C:\example\"));` gets highlighed

What does that even mean?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I'll probably still need the value I get from the string to use it on a progress bar, but I think that doesnt matter...

Comment: @IsaacSousa It means your static method has some kind of problem in it. Debugging the method when it is running would help you.